# stuck at simple trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

I'm reading  [paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15464-s13/assignments/assignment2/jlander_gamedev_sept98.pdf) on inverse kinematic using simple trigonometric equations.
In one part of the paper,
the author skipped straight to final equation without any derivation.
My trigonometric is not weak but I failed to derive below equations after spending an   hour or two.
I'm beginning to suspect the author is using some math "trick" to derive final equations.

$X = (L_1 \cos(\theta_1)) + (L_2\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2))$
$Y = (L_1 \sin(\theta_1)) + (L_2\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2))$

and given trigonometric identities

$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$
$\sin(a+b)=\cos(a)\sin(b)+sin(a)cos(b)$

I should get
$\theta_1 = \frac{-(L1\sin(\theta_2))x+(L_1+L_2\cos(\theta_2))y}{2L_1L_2}$

anyone can shed some light?

Comment: That doesn't look sound: are you sure you "should get" what you say, or some $\;\sin\;,\;\;\cos\;$ is lacking on the left side? Also, reading *slightly* the paper linked, you ommited quite some important equations in your question...

Comment: nope I rechecked again.The paper is wrong not me.I'm referring to page 12, equation 6 "By solving for $\theta_1$ using Equation 2
and the identities, you get the final
piece of the puzzle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\begin{align}&x=L_1\cos\theta_1+L_2(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)\\{}\\
&y=L_1\sin\theta_1+L_2(\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1)\end{align}$$

Multiply first equation by $\;-\sin\theta_1\;$ and the second one by $\;\cos\theta_1\;$ and add them:

$$-x\sin\theta_1+y\cos\theta_1=$$

$$=L_2\left(\color{red}{\sin^2\theta_1\sin\theta_2}-\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\color{red}{\sin\theta_2\cos^2\theta_1}\right)=L_2\sin\theta_2\implies$$

$$\sin\theta_2=\frac{y\cos\theta_1-x\sin\theta_1}{L_2}$$

Try to take it from here, though it doesn't look very nice and what you say you get for $\;\theta_1\;$ looks wrong.

Comment: thanks.I figure there's something wrong with the equation in the articles that I'm referring to and you just reaffirm my suspision.Thanks Timbuc, else I will be spending the whole night chasing my own shadow.